# Syncthing not accessible after having been working

Tags: command-line

When I try to open the web GUI it says it can't connect. I tried launching it from the terminal and this is what I get;

```
~$ syncthing
[start] 17:05:45 INFO: syncthing v1.18.0-ds1 "Fermium Flea" (go1.18.1 linux-amd64) debian@debian 2023-02-03 19:23:27 UTC
[start] 17:05:45 WARNING: Failed to initialize config: config file version (37) is newer than supported version (35). If this is expected, use -allow-newer-config to override.
[monitor] 17:05:45 INFO: Syncthing exited: exit status 1
[start] 17:05:46 INFO: syncthing v1.18.0-ds1 "Fermium Flea" (go1.18.1 linux-amd64) debian@debian 2023-02-03 19:23:27 UTC
[start] 17:05:46 WARNING: Failed to initialize config: config file version (37) is newer than supported version (35). If this is expected, use -allow-newer-config to override.
[monitor] 17:05:46 INFO: Syncthing exited: exit status 1
[start] 17:05:47 INFO: syncthing v1.18.0-ds1 "Fermium Flea" (go1.18.1 linux-amd64) debian@debian 2023-02-03 19:23:27 UTC
[start] 17:05:47 WARNING: Failed to initialize config: config file version (37) is newer than supported version (35). If this is expected, use -allow-newer-config to override.
[monitor] 17:05:47 INFO: Syncthing exited: exit status 1
[start] 17:05:48 INFO: syncthing v1.18.0-ds1 "Fermium Flea" (go1.18.1 linux-amd64) debian@debian 2023-02-03 19:23:27 UTC
[start] 17:05:48 WARNING: Failed to initialize config: config file version (37) is newer than supported version (35). If this is expected, use -allow-newer-config to override.
[monitor] 17:05:48 INFO: Syncthing exited: exit status 1
[monitor] 17:05:49 WARNING: 4 restarts in 4.06017486s; not retrying further
```

I don't know what to look at or take away from this. Any insight is well appreciated!

Comment: It's suggesting that the configuration file for your setup is newer than would be expected by the version of syncthing you're running. Have you run a newer version of syncthing on this system than the one you're launching now?

Comment: It's a fresh OS install and as far as I know I've only installed syncthing the one time. Would one of those updating commands fix it? like snap refresh I think it is? But I'm pretty sure syncthing is installed through apt.

Comment: Just ran sudo apt satisfy syncthing, and got "Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libflashrom1 libftdi1-2
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 16 not upgraded.".....Then I ran autoremove and tried syncthing again but no luck. I'll do a full shutdown again tonight and report back tomorrow if that fixes it.

Comment: Well, it looks like you installed syncthing from the archive, given the release number shown in your output. As it suggests, you can run `syncthing -allow-newer-config` and see if that works

Comment: Goddamn sir, that one little command just fixed everything lol. I'll be putting that one in my back pocket for future use!